# How to write a plsql procedure to generate excel with query data?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I need to create a procedure which generates a excel sheet including query output.
Please help!

Comment: If you have not seen this, please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11796016/oracle-query-output-in-excel), perhaps of some help

Comment: Hi Jacob, I have seen that but as i have found, ORA_EXCEL is paid utility. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Another option (free) is in the Alexandria PL/SQL Library - https://github.com/mortenbra/alexandria-plsql-utils - refer to XLSX_BUILDER_PKG

Answer (score 0):

Check out Rene Nyffenegger solution github: https://github.com/ReneNyffenegger/xlsx_writer-Oracle

As far as I'm aware there is no Oracle supplied package that generates xsl/xslx files

Answer (score 0):

You may create such a package (*Formerly we derived from Tom Kyte*) :

```
create or replace package to_excel is
 procedure xls(my_query in varchar2);
 procedure xls(my_query in varchar2,p_tip in varchar2);
 procedure xls2(my_query in varchar2); 
 procedure csv(my_query in varchar2,p_tip in varchar2);
end;

create or replace package body to_excel is
procedure xls(my_query in varchar2) is
begin
  owa_util.mime_header( ccontent_type => 'application/excel');
  --, ccharset => 'WE8ISO8859P9' ); -- , ccharset =>  'TR8MSWIN1254' , 'UTF-8'  
  owa_sylk.show( p_query=>replace(my_query,'x*x','%') );
end;

procedure xls(my_query in varchar2,p_tip in varchar2) is
begin
  owa_util.mime_header( 'application/excel' );
  owa_sylk.show( p_query=>replace(my_query,'x*x','%'), p_tip=>p_tip );
end;

procedure xls2(my_query in varchar2) is
begin
  owa_util.mime_header('application/vnd.ms-excel',false);
  htp.p('Cache-Control: no-store');
  htp.p('Expires: -1');
  owa_util.http_header_close;
  owa_sylk.show( p_query=>replace(my_query,'x*x','%') );

end;
procedure csv(my_query in varchar2,p_tip in varchar2) is
begin
  owa_util.mime_header( 'application/csv' );
  owa_sylk.show( p_query=>replace(my_query,'x*x','%'), p_tip=>p_tip );
end;


end;
```

that's a nice, useful method directly called from web browser such as `https://..../pls/<dad_name>/<schema_name>.to_excel.xls?my_query=select sysdate from dual`